# SQL Multi Lingual collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, multilingual, arabic, collation

We have a database (SQL Server 2016) which needs to store text from multiple languages (English, Arabic, Hebrew, Russian and French) and we do not know in advance which language the user will input.

We are using nvarchar for all text columns. However, we are unsure what collation would best serve this situation? For example if we do a search for firstname and we do not know the language that is used, how can we make sure we have the correct collation?

Also, for some reason when we perform inserts, values are stored correctly with or without using N for all languages (both `insert into tbl_users (firstname) values ('David')` and `insert into tbl_users (firstname) values (N'David')` work. However, when we try to update values, we experience problems if we do not use N in some languages. For example:

```
Update tbl_users set firstname = N'ديفيد' works in Arabic
```

`Update tbl_users set firstname = 'ديفيد'` does not work in Arabic (question marks are stored)

This problem is specific to Arabic. Shouldn't the fact that we defined the column as nvarchar be enough?

Comment: A national character literal should be preceded with an N if non-ASCII characters are included. (It has nothing to do with collations, just the data type.)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and collation handling is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Just stating that N should be used does not explain why INSERT works and UPDATE does not, and why this difference is only for Arabic.